# Elastic Collision Logic Leading to Twitchy Balls When Combined with Gravity

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

## Problem Description

I'm currently creating a Canvas based app that simulates balls and gravity. After the balls collide, their position is resolved and their velocity is calculated depending upon the angle they collide. However, once the balls begin to settle, they become "twitchy" and won't stop moving. How can I solve this?

## The Relevant code

```
bindToScreen(s) {
    if (this.position.y + this.radius > s.height) {
        this.position.y = s.height - this.radius;
        this.velocity.y *= -this.bounce;
    }

    if (this.position.y - this.radius < 0) {
        this.position.y = this.radius;
        this.velocity.y *= -1;
    }

    if (this.position.x + this.radius > s.width) {
        this.position.x = s.width - this.radius;
        this.velocity.x *= -1;
    }

    if (this.position.x - this.radius < 0) {
        this.position.x = this.radius;
        this.velocity.x *= -1;
    }
}

handleCollision(p2, s) {
    let d      = this.position.distanceVector(p2);
    let angle  = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x),
        spread = (this.radius + p2.radius) - this.position.distanceBetween(p2) + 1,
        ax     = spread * Math.cos(angle),
        ay     = spread * Math.sin(angle);

    // Separate
    this.position.x -= ax * 2;
    this.position.y -= ay * 2;


    // Bounce
    this.velocity.x -= Math.cos(angle);
    this.velocity.y -= Math.sin(angle);
    p2.velocity.x += Math.cos(angle);
    p2.velocity.y += Math.sin(angle);

    if (this.position.x + this.radius + this.velocity.x > s.width) {
        this.position.x = s.width - this.radius;
    }

    if (this.position.y + this.radius + this.velocity.y > s.height) {
        this.position.y = s.height - this.radius;
    }

    this.bindToScreen(s);
}
```

## Resources I've used to put this code together

> 1. [A tutorial on ball collisions](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769)
> 2. [A stack overflow question that helped with the angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497287/elastic-2d-ball-collision-using-angles)

#### Update

As per AlbertoSinigaglia's suggestion, I tried to null the velocity if it was sufficiently small after a collision. However, that results in even weirder behaviour like floaty balls after a couple of collisions. Fiddle showing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nbaxoztu/). I thought this may have been the gravity continuously increasing the `y` velocity, so I tried setting that to 0 too. Same problem.

```
    // If velocity is very small, set it to 0
    if(this.velocity.y > -0.1 && this.velocity.y < 0.1){
        this.velocity.y = 0;
        this.gravity = 0;
    }

    if(this.velocity.x > -1 && this.velocity.x < 1){
        this.velocity.x = 0;
    }
```

## A full snippet

The code is unfortunately pretty long, so here's a hidden snippet.

```js
class Canvas{
    constructor(w, h){
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.element = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.ctx = this.element.getContext('2d');

        this.element.width = this.width;
        this.element.height = this.height;
    }

    clear(){
        this.element.width = this.width;
    }

    drawCircle(c){
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.ctx.fillStyle = c.color;
        this.ctx.fill();
        this.ctx.closePath();
    }
}

class Vector2D{
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    add(v){
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
    }

    sub(v){
        this.x -= v.x;
        this.y -= v.y;
    }

    mul(v){
        this.x *= v.x;
        this.y *= v.y;
    }

    div(v){
        this.x /= v.x;
        this.y /= v.y;
    }
    
    distanceVector(v2){
        return new Vector2D(v2.x-this.x, v2.y-this.y);
    }

    distanceBetween(v2){
        let dx = v2.x - this.x;
        let dy = v2.y - this.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    }
}

class Circle{
    constructor(x, y, r, c){
        this.position = new Vector2D(x, y);
        this.radius = r;
        this.color = c;
    }

    get x(){
        return this.position.x;
    }

    get y(){
        return this.position.y;
    }  

    collision(c2){
        return this.position.distanceBetween(c2) < this.radius + c2.radius;
    }

    render(s){
        s.drawCircle(this);
    }
}

class Particle extends Circle {
    constructor(x, y, r, c, v) {
        super(x, y, r, c);
        this.velocity = new Vector2D(v.x, v.y);
        this.mass     = this.radius;
        this.gravity  = 0.8;
        this.bounce   = 0.8;
        this.resistance = 0.5;
    }
    
    bindToScreen(s) {
        if (this.position.y + this.radius > s.height) {
            this.position.y = s.height - this.radius;
            this.velocity.y *= -this.bounce;
        }
        
        if (this.position.y - this.radius < 0) {
            this.position.y = this.radius;
            this.velocity.y *= -1;
        }
        
        if (this.position.x + this.radius > s.width) {
            this.position.x = s.width - this.radius;
            this.velocity.x *= -1;
        }
        
        if (this.position.x - this.radius < 0) {
            this.position.x = this.radius;
            this.velocity.x *= -1;
        }
    }
    
    checkCollisions(p, s) {
        p.forEach(p2 => {
            if (p2 !== this) {
                if (this.collision(p2)) {
                    this.handleCollision(p2, s);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    handleCollision(p2, s) {
        let d      = this.position.distanceVector(p2);
        let angle  = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x),
            spread = (this.radius + p2.radius) - this.position.distanceBetween(p2) + 1,
            ax     = spread * Math.cos(angle),
            ay     = spread * Math.sin(angle);
        
        // Separate
        this.position.x -= ax * 2;
        this.position.y -= ay * 2;
    
    
        // Bounce
        this.velocity.x -= Math.cos(angle);
        this.velocity.y -= Math.sin(angle);
        p2.velocity.x += Math.cos(angle);
        p2.velocity.y += Math.sin(angle);
    
        if (this.position.x + this.radius + this.velocity.x > s.width) {
            this.position.x = s.width - this.radius;
        }
    
        if (this.position.y + this.radius + this.velocity.y > s.height) {
            this.position.y = s.height - this.radius;
        }
        
        this.bindToScreen(s);
    }
    
    update(s) {
        this.velocity.y += this.gravity;
        this.velocity.x *= -this.resistance;
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
        this.bindToScreen(s);
    }
}

class Game{
    constructor(){
        this.screen = new Canvas(800, 600);
        this.particles = [];
        this.particleCount = 10;
        this.particleSize = 20;
        this.delay = 25;
    }

    run(){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.particleCount; i++){
            let _this = this;

            setTimeout(() => {
                _this.particles.push(new Particle(this.particleSize, this.particleSize, this.particleSize, 'red', {x: 7, y: 7}));
            }, _this.delay * i);
        }

        this.loop();
    };

    update(){
        this.particles.forEach(particle => particle.update(this.screen));
    };

    checkCollisions(){
        this.particles.forEach(particle => particle.checkCollisions(this.particles, this.screen));
    }

    render(){
        this.screen.clear();
        this.particles.forEach(particle => particle.render(this.screen));
    };

    loop(){
        this.update();
        this.checkCollisions();
        this.render();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
    }
}

let game = new Game();
game.run();
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    background-color: #efefef;
}

canvas{
    width: 800px;
    height : 600px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: when it collide, if the resulting vector is very small, set it to 0

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Unfortunately, that results in even weirder stuff happening (like the balls floating upwards after a couple of collisions). I thought this was caused by the gravity constantly increasing the `y` velocity, but even setting that to 0 still causes the _floaty_ thing to happen - [see this for an example of the floaty thing](https://jsfiddle.net/nbaxoztu/)